# What's the current preferred way of using R Selenium without a server?

Tags: r, selenium, web-scraping, phantomjs

I have a work intensive part of a project I want to automatise, essentially I need to copy text from hundreds of web pages manually, using the same routine for each web page. No API is available so I would need to do this via web scraping. Since I will be handling confidential data I don't really feel confortable routing the information through a Selenium server.

I stumbled on [this article](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSelenium/vignettes/headless.html), describing a browser called PhantomJS which would allow me to use RSelenium without first connecting to a server. Sadly, however, the code in the vignette is outdated and the Phantom()-function is no longer functional.

Does PhantomJS still work with RSelenium and/or is there a better way if you'd want to use RSelenium without a server?

Comment: You may be interested in [`splashr`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/splashr/index.html). Source: https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/WebTechnologies.html